# Get-ChildItem trailing space in path

Tags: powershell

I have a folder on my fileshare that has a trailing lead. I can't for the love of me get the content with Get-ChildItem.

```
Get-ChildItem "\\fileshare\Projects\Videos\208 "
Get-ChildItem "\\fileshare\Projects\Videos\208` "
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\fileshare\Projects\Videos\208 "
```

It says that the specified path doesn't exist...

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a folder yourself in explorer with a trailing space - you will find you cannot as explorer removes the trailing space. This is because a file/folder with a trailing space is an invalid name in the Win32 namespace.

PowerShell is also stripping the trailing space from the folder name (the same as explorer does), which means the command is then trying to run against a folder that does not exist which thus the 'path doesn't exist' error.

See Cause 6 from [You cannot delete a file or a folder on an NTFS file system volume](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/320081/you-cannot-delete-a-file-or-a-folder-on-an-ntfs-file-system-volume) as this covers invalid namespaces. (The article references Windows XP but is relevant to any Windows OS using an NTFS filesystem)

PowerShell will likely not be able to read this folder either, unless you use the workaround `\\?\c:\path_to_problem_file` that the article mentions.

You should really remove or rename this folder as it's going to cause you further problems in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**Just add a trailing backslash... like this:**

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\fileshare\Projects\Videos\208 \"
```

**Extra info:**

It is probably not a space but the "*Alt+255*" character.
If you search for the 255 char in the extended ascii table you will find a character that looks like a space but doesn't behave like a space.

As people noted it is not possible to create a folder with a trailing space, but it is possible to create a folder with a trailing "*Alt+255* " character.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a wildcard in a situation like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\fileshare\Projects\Videos\208*"
```

I am only assuming, but the '\fileshare' is located on a OS X or Mac OS, which does allow spaces in the folder structure.

Comment: That could certainly lead to unexpected behaviour as it will match _every_ folder that begins with 208

Comment: How do you figure? It will only find the 208 located in the directory of 'Videos. 'The OP said that he wants to find a file with  `'$Filepath\208  '`. If you use a wildcard it will find any files in that directory with 208 yes, but OP never stated that the directory Videos contains more than one 208 . He simply asked I can't get Get-ChildItem to work.

Comment: OP doesn't provide any indication to what his code is doing, we only have a single command. I think it's only fair to raise that your answer could potentially match content that he does not want.